# GFCI not resetting

Tags: electrical

A GFCI outlet in my kitchen is currently dead and is not reset. Even though I keep pushing the reset button, the click sound does not happen. I also found that there was no power going to the GFCI outlet when I checked it with a non-contact voltage. There is no other outlet in the visible area between the circuit breaker and the GFCI outlet but there might be in the hidden spaces :(

Before giving up and calling a professional electrician, I am wondering if there is anything I can do.

Comment: You can try pressing the test button and then pressing the reset button.

Comment: Is there power at the breaker?  If there's no power at the LINE terminals of the GFCI, it will not set.  That is by design. You'll have to determine the problem between the breaker and the GFCI, which will likely require somebody to be on site, or a lot more information.

Answer (score 1):

Check the breaker in your panel to see if it is tripped. Some don't look tripped and only move slightly so check them all unless you know exactly which one it is. I believe an older GFCI will not reset without power to it.

Comment: The breaker is turned back on but there is no power to the outlet.

Comment: It is possible the outlet is bad, I have to replace them all the time on garbage disposals & circuits that use blenders these are the hardest on the circuitry.  when checking the outlet make sure the wires to it are good/ the feed may have come loose in the back. Turn power off, pull it out, turn power on. Check it to verify power to the outlet/  make sure you have the correct breaker.